# PostgreSQL json aggregation issue

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

How with Postgres aggregation function merge one object as element in array field in parent object.

What need

Sector

### [image: Sector]

Project

### [image: Project]

Result

[image: Result]

My SQL request.

`select row_to_json(t)
from (
  select id, data, 
  (
    select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(p)))
    from (
      select id, data
      from public."Project"
      where (s.data -» 'projectId') :: UUID = id
    ) p
  ) as projects
  from public."Sector" s
) t;`

It don't work, because **projects** is null. But need, unwind data field and merge **projectId** in *data* with **Project** table. Like *unwind* and *lookup* in MongoDB.